# How to convert XML file to JSON in Angular 8?

Tags: angular8

I have tried to import on this way:

```
import { NgxXml2jsonService } from 'ngx-xml2json';
```

For some reason the import doesn't work. Here is some other code:

```
let parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
let xml = "<root>Hello xml2js!</root>"

parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
});
```

Comment: Did you inject the NgxXml2jsonService in the constructor of the component?

Comment: Could you please post the whole component? This would be very useful to find out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The `NgxXml2jsonService package` is really old. You need to use the `xml2js package.`

**Here is the usage:**

```
import * as xml2js from 'xml2js';
    this.responseAsJson = this.parseXml(this.parser.parseFromString(trimmedVal, 'text/xml'));
    parseXml(xmlData: any) {
    const parser = new xml2js.Parser();

    parser.parseString(xmlData, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error parsing XML:', err);
      } else {
        return result;
      }
    });
  }
```

Also, you might need to install **timer** and **stream** packages